# How to print std::system_error what() for all languages

Tags: c++, windows-console

When printing `what()` from a Windows console app, it works in English but running it in Korean for instance the output is all question marks like:

```
"?????? ???????????????."
```

The below code is what I have tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int wmain(void)
{
  try
  {
    throw std::system_error(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, std::system_category());
  }

  catch (const std::system_error &e)
  {
    std::wcout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: do you expect it to be translated? is that the problem?

Comment: Is your locale and regional settings of the OS set up properly? Have you tried printing the (narrow character) string using `std::cout`? And the Windows console is historically usually not very nice with e.g. UTF-8 encoded output.

Comment: Your console window might not have a corresponding font to print in Korean with.

Comment: Note the console does properly display the Korean font at the command prompt. I peeked inside the implementation of what() which may offer a clue. It uses FormatMessageW followed by WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, ...).